# unable to create a hover/stationary chart in excel using vba macro

Tags: vba

I am trying to create an excel chart that is always visible while I scroll vertically through the long data set I have. I want this to happen for all the worksheets in my workbook. 
After going through many helpful links online, I have tried something like below, however, without success.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer, j As Integer, a As Integer, b As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws

        '<much happens here>

        Set chartxval = .Range("A2:A" & (l - 1))
        Set chartval = .Range("E2:E" & (l - 1))
        With .Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
            .ChartStyle = 240
            .Application.CutCopyMode = False
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = chartxval
            .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = chartval
        End With
        ws.Activate
        With ActiveWindow.VisibleRange
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Top = .Top + 5
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Left = .Left + .Width - _
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Width - 45
        End With
    End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

This code only creates the charts in various sheets but it isn't able to give a hovering or stationary chart, as is required. 
Help required from anyone who may have any idea how to go about achieving the desired result! Thanks in advance!

Comment: skipped a line just after the first line:  _Dim i As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer, j As Integer, a As Integer, b As Integer_

Comment: Can't you just build the chart at the top of the sheet and freeze panes?

Comment: That option isn't useful because I happen to have a very big chart.